# Where the following propagation model arise in practice

Tags: statistics, social-network-analysis

This is in continuation to a previos question. I would like to know where in practice will the following M-ary tree-structured social network propagation model arise. I am looking for some concrete examples in social media (twitter and youtube etc.). Eventually, I want to do some statistical analysis on such social networks.

[image: Example of a binary tree-structured social network]

Comment: Can you please provide some info about your previous question, and link? Perhaps you should just revise that question. Hard to say without any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine each node in your graph as a user, and each edge as an action such as 'share'. It may also be a bidirectional relationship 'share' and 'view'.

Some social scientists and engineers estimate the probability that a message is 'shared' and 'viewed' given that a particular user decides to share it. This process is called "information diffusion", "information propagation", "cascading", etc.

If you are interested in the details of how these calculations are performed, check out these papers:

http://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/netrate-netsci14.pdf

http://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/cascades-www14.pdf

http://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/infopath-wsdm13.pdf

Similar topics:
http://snap.stanford.edu/papers.html

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thanks for your reply.